# Not able to access ms crm page using "parent.window.xrm.page" from aspx page through chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, dynamics-crm

we are getting exception "Blocked a frame with origin "https:domain1:port1" from accessing a frame with origin "https:domain1:port2". Protocols, domains, and ports must match". at the code "window.parent.Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("entityName", null, parameters, windowOptions);" in MS CRM 2015

We are loading custom page in sitemap(not in iframe of any entity) by providing the CutomWEBAPPs’URL at Sitemap level. When trying to access the XRM of the parent page we are getting the above error.

This is working fine in IE11 but fails with the above error in chrome and firefox.

Did anyone faced this issue? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into cross frame scripting issues here which is more to do with browsers in general than CRM.

There is content [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328034.aspx) which suggests using `Window.postMessage` instead. There are some further links in that article which provide additional detail.

> There are times when you want to enable communication for an IFRAME
>   that contains content on a different domain. `Window.postMessage` is a
>   browser method that provides this capability for versions of Internet
>   Explorer no earlier than Internet Explorer 8. Google Chrome, Mozilla
>   Firefox, and Apple Safari also support it

That said [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328483.aspx) article suggests just using `window.open` which maybe be the easiest solution in this case.

> Outside the application, where pages do not have access to the
>   `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` function, use `window.open` or a link to open
>   a specific record or form for an entity.